# Why std::move is needed?

Tags: c++, c++11

I read a [beautiful article](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html) on the move semantics in C++11. This article is written in a very intuitive way. The example class in the article is given below.

```
class ArrayWrapper 
{ 
public: 
    // default constructor produces a moderately sized array 
    ArrayWrapper () 
        : _p_vals( new int[ 64 ] ) 
        , _metadata( 64, "ArrayWrapper" ) 
    {} 

    ArrayWrapper (int n) 
        : _p_vals( new int[ n ] ) 
        , _metadata( n, "ArrayWrapper" ) 
    {} 

    // move constructor 
    ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other) 
        : _p_vals( other._p_vals  ) 
        , _metadata( other._metadata ) 
    { 
        other._p_vals = NULL; 
    } 

    // copy constructor 
    ArrayWrapper (const ArrayWrapper& other) 
        : _p_vals( new int[ other._metadata.getSize() ] ) 
        , _metadata( other._metadata ) 
    { 
        for ( int i = 0; i < _metadata.getSize(); ++i ) 
        { 
            _p_vals[ i ] = other._p_vals[ i ]; 
        } 
    } 
    ~ArrayWrapper () 
    { 
        delete [] _p_vals; 
    } 
private: 
    int *_p_vals; 
    MetaData _metadata; 
};
```

Clearly in the above move constructor implementation, the movement doesn't happen for the the embedded element `_metadata`. To facilitate this the trick is to use the `std::move()` method like this.

```
ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other) 
        : _p_vals( other._p_vals  ) 
        , _metadata( std::move( other._metadata ) ) 
{ 
    other._p_vals = NULL; 
}
```

So far, so good.

The standard says:

§5 (C++11 §5[expr]/6):

> [ Note: An expression is an xvalue if it is:
>
> - the result of calling a function, whether implicitly or explicitly,
>     whose return type is an rvalue reference to object type,
> - a cast to an rvalue reference to object type,
> - a class member access expression designating a non-static data member
>     of non-reference type in which the object expression is an xvalue, or
> - a `.*` pointer-to-member expression in which the first operand is an
>     xvalue and the second operand is a pointer to data member.

My question:

Now, the variable `other` in the move constructor is an xvalue (am I right?). Then according to the last rule above, `other._metadata` should also be an xvalue. And hence the compiler can implicitely use the move constructor of `_metadata`'s class. So, no need to `std::move` here.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid leading underscores to prevent accidentally using a reserved name.

Comment: Good habit to get into. In this example, none start with capitals, so you're ok, but you can easily forget not to do that.

Comment: @MarkB : It is not my code. I just reproduced it from the refered article.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your assumption is not really true. The argument to the constructor is an `xvalue`, which allows the rvalue-reference to be bound, but once the rvalue-reference is bound, inside the constructor, it is no longer an `xvalue` but an `lvalue`. Conceptually, the object at the call place is *expiring*, but inside the constructor and until it completes it is no longer *expiring*, as it can be used later within the constructor block.

```
ArrayWrapper f();
ArrayWrapper r = f();   // [1]
```

In [1], the expression `f()` refers to a temporary, that will *expire* after the call to the constructor, so it can be bound by an rvalue-reference.

```
ArrayWrapper (ArrayWrapper&& other) 
    : _p_vals( other._p_vals  ) 
    , _metadata( other._metadata )        // [2] 
{ 
    other._p_vals = NULL; 
    std::cout << other._metadata << "\n"; // [3]
}
```

Inside the constructor, `other` is not expiring, it will be alive for each and every instruction of the constructor. If the compiler allowed *moving* in [2], than a potential further use of the variable in [3] would be invalid. You have to explicitly tell the compiler that you want the value to expire *now*.

Comment: OK, I think I get it. So, this means, f() in [1] is an xvalue, but, 'other' in the function parameter is not an xvalue, right?

Comment: @PermanentGuest: right, an rvalue-reference (once bound) is an lvalue.

Answer (score 9):

`other` is an lvalue, because it's a variable. Named references are lvalues, regardless of what kind of reference they are.